# I am trying to write an Excel VBA macro and XML in order to query a SharePoint site for the View Names and GUIDs for a specific list

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am struggling with the proper XML syntax in order to retrieve all SharePoint View Names and GUIDs associated with a specific List Name and GUID.   I found a similar piece of VBA code that returns all of the List Names and their GUIDs, which works perfectly.  I have tried unsuccessfully to adapt that code retrieve the View Names and GUIDs.

When I run the code below I receive the following statusText "Internal Server Error"

```
Sub GetViewGUIDs()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim RespText As String
    Dim xmlhtp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim iLeng As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Rowcnt As Long
    Dim ListGUID As String

    ListGUID = "{3ABAA8A3-C75D-4A57-BC7F-490443E381A2}"
    
    sURL = "https://yoursharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_vti_bin/views.asmx"
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <GetViewCollectionResponse xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/""><listName>" & ListGUID & "</listName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <GetViewCollectionResult><xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetViewCollectionResult>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    </GetViewCollectionResponse>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
    
    Set xmlhtp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
     
    With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Host", "webservices.gama-system.com"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "soapAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetViewCollection"
        .send sEnv
        xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With
    
    RespText = xmlhtp.responseText

‘   more code here to parse the RespText and pick out the View Names and associated GUIDs
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.depaul.edu/academics/undergraduate/_vti_bin/views.asmx?op=GetViewCollection

Looks like you're sending the *response* XML as the request.

This works for me:

```vb
Sub GetViewGUIDs()
    Dim sURL As String, sEnv As String, ListGUID As String
    Dim xmlhtp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
   
    ListGUID = "{3ABAA8A3-C75D-4A57-BC7F-490443E381A2}"
    
    sURL = "https://yourCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site001/_vti_bin/views.asmx"
    
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " & _
              "xmlns:xsd = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" " & _
              "xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
              "<soap:Body>" & _
                "<GetViewCollection xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">" & _
                     "<listName>" & ListGUID & "</listName>" & _
                "</GetViewCollection>" & _
              "</soap:Body>" & _
          "</soap:Envelope>"
    
    Set xmlhtp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
     
    With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "soapAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetViewCollection"
        .send sEnv
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Did Tim Williams' answer help you?